# Conditional Format VBA not running

Tags: excel, vba

I created two Private Sub's to run when a cell change occurs in my sheet. If the value in the last column (I) of the row is "F", then the font color for the row should change to green, if the cell value is "L", then the font color in that row should be gold. This ran once but will no longer work if I change the cell values between "F" and "L". Need to know why it no longer works with a cell change.

```
Private Sub ConForL_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cfl As Long

cfl = Worksheets("Sorts 2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sorts 2").Range("B2:I" & cfl)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=$I2=""L"""
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ConForF_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cff As Long

cff = Worksheets("Sorts 2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sorts 2").Range("B2:I" & cff)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=$I2=""F"""
        '.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're attempting to use the Worksheet.Change event, note that you can't rename the event handler. It has to be `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: Well, that was simple and this became a dumb question. Thanks.

Comment: But why would you use VBA for this instead of the basic conditional formatting?

Comment: Inside the "Worksheet_Change" code you  would have two `If` Blocks to test which column changed